# About evaluation in Block

Tags: evaluation

I'm completely puzzled by the following codes:

```
Clear[func, f]
a = x^2 + z;
func[k_] := Block[{f}, (f[x_] := Evaluate[(a /. {z -> k})]; f[1])]
func[2]
```

> ```
> 2+x^2
> ```

But I think it should be `3`, i.e., `2+1^2=3`.

Actually for the following code:

```
 f[x_] := Evaluate[(a /. {z -> k})]; f[1]
```

The output is 3.

Can you explain the evaluation inside the `Block`?

Taking Simon Woods' advice, for

```
func[k_] := 
 Block[{f, tmp}, (tmp = Evaluate[a /. z -> k]; f[x_] = tmp; f[1])]

Trace[func[2]]
```

gives,

> {func[2],Block[{f,tmp},tmp = Evaluate[a /. z -> 2],f[x_] = tmp; f[1]],...}

But, for the codes

```
func[k_] := Block[{f}, (f[x_] = Evaluate[a /. z -> k]; f[1])]
Trace[func[2]]
```

gives,

> {func[2],Block[{f},f[x$_] = Evaluate[a /. z -> 2];f[1],...}

I notice that the arguments of `f` inside the `Block` are different in these two cases, and that is the reason.

But why is the difference?

Comment: You can do `func[k_] := Block[{y = (a /. {z -> k}), f}, (f[x_] = y; f[1])]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes,I've notice this:func[k_] := 
 Block[{f, tmp}, (tmp = Evaluate[a /. z -> k]; f[x_] = tmp; f[1])] But why?

Comment: Have a look at `Trace[func[2]]`

Comment: @Simon Woods, see my edit, I will appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested scoping constructs like Module or SetDelayed apply a variable renaming, adding the  symbol ($) to each variable.
For that, take a look at the internal form of f, as you defined it

```
func[k_] := Block[{f}, 
                  f[x_] := Evaluate[ReplaceAll[a, {z -> k}]];
                  Information[f];
                  Trace[f[1]]]

func[2]

Global`f
f[x$_]:=2+x^2

{f[1], 2+x^2}
```

the function f accepts any argument and gives the name x\$ to it. Then goes to evaluate the right-hand side and looks for any occurrence of x\$ so to make the replacement with 1, in that case. Unfortunately, the global variable a (that defined externally) depends on x and not on x$ so no replacement happens.
A possible solution is to change the name of the variable x so to avoid confusion and make clear the replacement of such variable inside the ReplaceAll.

```
func[k_] := Block[{f},
                   f[var_] := Evaluate[ReplaceAll[a, {z -> k, x -> var}]];
                   Information[f];
                   Trace[f[1]]]


func[2]
Global`f
f[var$_]:=2+var$^2

{f[1], 2+1^2}, {1^2, 1}, 2+1, 3}
```

Comment: `Block` is not to blame for the symbol renaming but the outermost `SetDelayed` realising that your `k` is being injected in the innermost `SetDelayed`

Comment: @Rojo thanks, you are right. My answer is not correct in the explanation. I have to edit it and adjust. Indeed, doing some further tests I can confirm that the nesting of SetDelayed seems to be the cause of the renaming of var to var$. Honestly I still have to fully understand why, so at a glance I thought it was just Block.

Comment: @Rojo please let me know if I have to delete/edit/add my answer. I'm new on SE. I have seen there is a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733239/lexical-and-dynamic-scoping-in-mathematica-local-variables-with-module-with-a) with similar issue described: "If you look deep in the examples in the [reference page for `Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html?q=Module&lang=en), under the section labeled **Possible Issues**, there's a little note that says _"Variables are renamed in nested scopes"_".

Comment: Sure, when you see a way to improve or correct your answer its better if you edit it. Welcome to SE :)

Comment: To correct this, simply note that it is Function and not Block that is using the dollar sign to support a lexical scoping-like behavior.