# NDSolve produces zombies

Tags: differential-equations, memory

I am using Mathematica 10.1 and when I execute `NDSolve` then there are temporary variables produced every time I call it. This seems not to happen when I explicitly use the finite elements method. Here is an example:

```
Names["Global`*"]
erg = NDSolveValue[{ft''[x] == -2*ft[x], ft[0] == 1, ft[3] == 2},ft,{x, 0, 3}];
MemoryInUse[]
erg = NDSolveValue[{ft''[x] == -2*ft[x], ft[0] == 1, ft[3] == 2},ft, {x, 0, 3}];
erg = NDSolveValue[{ft''[x] == -2*ft[x], ft[0] == 1, ft[3] == 2},ft, {x, 0, 3}];
Names["Global`*"]  
MemoryInUse[]
```

As one can see there are many ft$**** variables and the memory in use has increased. Is this a bug and how can I tackle it?

Comment: This answer to another question on this site, might be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28774/8822

Comment: In principle I understand how Module or such things treat local variables but shouldn't they get removed after the routine has finished? I have the problem that multiple calls of `NDSolve` trash my memory. Could that be related to the `NIntegrate` memory bug?

Comment: Ran your code under 10.3 on Windows 10 (64).  MemoryInUse[] first gave `57705936`, then `57838288`.  I next executed, `Remove["ft$", "ft$1249", "ft$1250", "ft$1300", "ft$1301", "ft$1348", "ft$1349", x$]` and received `Remove::relex: Cannot remove lexical symbol ft$ except automatically (when ft is removed). >>`.  Same for `x$`.  Then, `Names["Global`*"] ` gave `{"erg", "ft", "ft$", "x", "x$"}`, and `MemoryInUse[]` gave `64285904`.  Finally, executed `erg` and again executed `MemoryInUse[]`, which gave `75681560` Increasing memory was a surprise.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I have a large simulation where I call `NDSolve` several times until eventually my memory is full. I have already tried `Clear` and `Remove` but none of them released the memory.

Comment: Strangely, if I save the notebook, restart Mathematica, and rerun the saved notebook (with the new `ft$...` used in `Remove`) the `MemoryInUse` results` drop to `30488608`, `30621032`, `40877848`, and `52248136`, respectively.

Comment: I find the title unintentionally amusing. Talk about unexpected side effects!

Comment: It is worth to mention that in version 8.0.4 both `MemoryInUse[]` and `MaxMemoryUsed[]` return about 18300000, while in versions 10.4.1 and 11.1.0 they return 36400000 (the solutions returned are exactly identical).